# IBM Websphere 8.5.5 unable to detect Spring when used java config

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, web-deployment, ibm-was

I have working Spring application which works fine on Tomcat . I am using Java Config to load all beans and config , my app code mostly contains spring components but i also have few async servlet. When i deploy the war in IBM WebSphere the application is getting deployed but spring is not getting initialized i.e non of spring beans are initialized but asyc servlet are working fine. I dont see any error log but i see few warning , below are those

```
W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-210189610 ( org.hibernate.annotations.JoinColumnOrFormula.formula ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/JoinFormula; ] Call in violation of protocol
W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-482978983 ( org.hibernate.annotations.JoinColumnOrFormula.column ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Ljavax/persistence/JoinColumn; ] Call in violation of protocol
W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-1529286857 ( org.hibernate.annotations.Table.foreignKey ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/ForeignKey; ] Call in violation of protocol
W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@1310727123 ( org.hibernate.annotations.Table.sqlInsert ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/SQLInsert; ] Call in violation of protocol
W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@251574898 ( org.hibernate.annotations.Table.sqlUpdate ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/SQLUpdate; ] Call in violation of protocol
W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@15024097 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@-1168467436 ( org.hibernate.annotations.Table.sqlDelete ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Lorg/hibernate/annotations/SQLDelete; ] Call in violation of protocol
W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.AnnotationInfoDefaultVisitor visitAnnotation [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.InfoVisitor@-179906720 ] for method [ com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@1056720732 ( javax.persistence.AssociationOverride.joinTable ) ] Name [ null ] Description [ Ljavax/persistence/JoinTable; ] Call in violation of protocol
```

I tried to deploy a simple spring app which will have configuration in xml files , this application was loaded successfully.

Is there any problem deploying spring java config application in IBM WAS 8.5.5.0